# ChartJS click on bar and change it's background color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chartjs to paint a simple bar chart. The bar chart is clickable and I notice if the user clicks on a bar. Now I'd like to change the background of the bar that has been clicked to indicate that this bar is actively selected.

Is this possible?

Thx

Edit: I've added a small example.
https://jsfiddle.net/10n39cLz/1/
The clicked element will be collected using: `this.getElementAtEvent(e)`

Comment: You can change the background color of an element via `element[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = "rgb(255,255,255)";`. Note that this works only till you select the second one but you should be able to find out how to reset the color to the original one. I don't know if it's the intended way to do it like this but thats what I got to work through your fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this also colors the rest of the bars on refresh as it is only one series of data.. :-/

Comment: Yep saw it right now too. I will check if I'm able to get it to work and edit this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a pretty elegant solution By just modifying the backgroundColor saved within an array. Sadly a render() wasn't enough, therefor I need to do an update()..

Wish I could use ES6 by the way :-)

```
var backgroundColor = ['rgb(124, 181, 236)',
    'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
    'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
    'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
    'rgb(124, 181, 236)',
    'rgb(124, 181, 236)'];

var a = new Chart(document.getElementById("trendChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor
    }]      
  },
  options:{
    onClick: function(e){
    var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
            for(var i=0;i<backgroundColor.length;i++){
        backgroundColor[i] = 'rgb(124, 181, 236)';
    }
         backgroundColor[element[0]._index] = 'red';
      this.update()
    },
           scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
            fontColor:'#fff'
           }
        }],
                    xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
            fontColor:'#fff'
          }
         }],                    
     },
   legend:{
      display:false
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: This works well, other than I had to add the "selected" color at the correct index when iterating the background color array or it was reset immediately after.

Answer (score 3):

If you spend some time *playing* with the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console) and your element, you see that if you `log` your element, you will have an array with only one object (the said element).

This object has itself several children, such as `_index` (what you used in your fiddle).
This is where you should start editing your element background.

If you go very deep inside the `_chart` child, you can finally edit the bar you want.

I updated your fiddle to see the result : [here it is](https://jsfiddle.net/10n39cLz/5/).

---

**Note that** the effect will disappear if you [`mouseleave`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseleave) out of the element.

Comment: @Christian Updated the fiddle, tell me how it goes now

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I found a more elegant solution. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A little modification of the `active` property should give you the desired result.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("trendChart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(124, 181, 236)'
    }]      
  },
  options:{
    onClick: function(e){
    var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);

    // changes only the color of the active object
    this.active[0]._chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = "red";

    if(element.length > 0){
            alert("Clicked on a bar with index: "+element[0]._index+". Now this bar should be marked as active.");
      }
    },
           scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
            fontColor:'#fff'
           }
        }],
                    xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
            fontColor:'#fff'
          }
         }],                    
     },
   legend:{
      display:false
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This also colors every bar red if you hover over them after setting it for one ;) Same error as in my comment.

Comment: Seems like you both have the right suggestion, but to get this running, I need to configure a series of data for each bar...